# extreamly slow image download speed

Tags: java, outputstream

I have a java web application, where users can download images
The way i coded the download is using IOUtils.copy to the response stream
But downloading a 4mb image takes around 10 sec and its happening really slow.
It seems like the server is sending chunk at a time.

this is the way I am writing the image to the output stream:

```
 OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
 FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(path);
 IOUtils.copy(stream, out);
 out.flush();
 out.close();
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

**UPDATE**

following code using 1MB buffer and copyLarge didn't make any change.

```
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(path);
        byte[] buffer = new  byte[1024 * 1024];         
        IOUtils.copyLarge(stream, out,buffer );
```

Comment: 1. Check your connection speed. 4MB / 10sec is about 4Mbit / sec. 2. Check browser side timing via browser debug console - network tab (amount of connection time and download time)

Answer (score 1):

Try copyLarge:

```
public static long copyLarge(InputStream input,
             OutputStream output,
             byte[] buffer) throws IOException
```

Use buffer size about 1Mb

Comment: doc for Copy large says: Copies bytes from a large (over 2GB) InputStream to an OutputStream.

Comment: Try it with reasonable buffer size (say, 1Mb or even 4Mb if you have enough RAM), hardly likely it will speed up the operation. Please take care to have separated buffer for each thread (create is as local variable in a method for example). If you have heavy load, you may have pool of buffers, but again take care that buffers should not be used in multiple threads simultaneously.

Comment: didnt make any change.